# Different result in Laravel with distinct in mysql

Tags: php, debugging, laravel-5

Hi all I  just want to know, how this query

```
Log::selectRaw(\DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT(`mac`)) AS `visits`"))
        ->where('type', 'anonymous_login')
        ->where('created_at', 'LIKE', '2015-08-17%' )
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->dates['from'], $this->dates['to']])
        ->first();
```

can return result '3'

and this query to return me '5'

```
Log::selectRaw(\DB::raw("COUNT(id) AS `visits`"))
        ->where('type', 'anonymous_login')
        ->where('created_at', 'LIKE', '2015-08-17%' )
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->dates['from'], $this->dates['to']])
        ->distinct('mac')
        ->first();
```

I check both queries in play SQL return me 5.

Also checked QueryLog of Laravel - queries are same as I execute them in SequelPro.

Result is same when I use GROUP BY.

Laravel version is 5.0

Comment: [distinct](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct) does not accept a parameter.

Comment: So with that can you try to add a select of the column `mac` and see what it returns?

Comment: Also... you need to provide some example data... Right now it looks like you have 5 rows that you're checking against. And it is more likely that if that is the case that the 3 is the correct result (as I'm about 55% sure not all 5 of those rows have different `mac` columns)

Comment: The right number of the count is 5, I get 5 no matter how I wrote the sql in sequelrpo, but in  ORM it return different values.